# List assignment index out of range Python

Tags: python

When i try to run this code,I am getting list assignment index out of range error in the line 7.

```
import random
    Matrix = [[0 for x in range(37)] for x in range(37)] 
    for i in range(0,37):
        for k in range(3,16):
            for j in range(0,k):
                y=random.randint(0,37)
                Matrix[i][y]=1
    for row in Matrix:
        print (row)
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: `randint` *includes* both endpoints.  So when it picks 37 things blow up since your valid indices are `0 <= i <= 36`.

Comment: You must be trying to index a location that doesn't exist? What are the values of ```i``` and ```y``` when the error occurs?  What are the dimensions of ```Matrix```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0 <= random.randint(0,37) <= 37` is always True.

I mean y will be 37!

but `Matrix` are list of list which has indexes 0 from **36** not 37

if you get the `Matrix[i][37]`, then you will see **index out of range error** !!

FIX

```
         y=random.randint(0,37)
```

to

```
         y=random.randint(0,36)
```